is it possible to create different types of Airflow worker pods and use them for different DAGs/Tasks?
Is it possible to specify multiple types of worker pods (Kubernetes pods) based on different configurations like CPU allocation, RAM allocation, Docker Image to use for container creation, etc? and then specify on which worker pod the given DAG or task should run?
I am new to airflow and have experience working with Microservices-based projects. I am evaluating if we can use airflow to replace event-driven microservice architecture for one of our upcoming project.

If you are open to managed airflow, I recommend looking at astronomer.io. I've been using it, and it's pretty easy to do this by creating custom worker queues. I am really not sure how to do this on self-hosted airflow though. Hence, making a comment instead of answering.

Yes, it is possible by using the airflow "queues" and "pools" concepts .
Create a worker pod "pod1" with the command as below:
airflow celery worker

When we do not specify any queue name , this particular airflow worker pod will execute tasks from the "default" queue .
You can specify the queue to which a worker pod should listen to ,  using this command
airflow celery worker -q new_queue

Create a new pod "pod2" using the above command .This particular pod "pod2" will execute tasks only from "new_queue" .
Create a  pool "new_pool" from airflow UI -> admin -> pools -> create pool.
Now you can specify the pool and queue when creating a task like this:
task1 = SomeOperator(
    
    param1=param1,
    param2=param2,
)

task2 = SomeOperator(
    
    param1=param1,
    param2=param2,

    pool = "new_pool",
    queue = "new_queue"
)

When scheduling the above 2 tasks , task1 will go to the default queue , and task2 will go to the new_queue .
So pod1 will pick up task1 and pod2 will pickup task2 .
Similarly you can create your own number of queues and worker pods .
Since the above 2 worker pods are different entities in kubernetes , you can assign specific configuration like memory , cpu , docker image etc for each worker pod .
Basically in terms of kubernetes , you will have different airflow-worker.yaml files for different worker configuration you require like :
default-queue-worker.yaml 

in which you assign its own docker image , cpu , memory etc and set the entrypoint command as airflow celery worker
new-queue-worker.yaml

again you assign its own config and here the entrypoint will be
airflow celery worker -q new_queue


could you leave here the docker compose for deploying this? thank you

@M.Mariscal I'm not familiar with deployments using docker-compose .You can refer the official airflow docker-compose file . Here , the command is just "celery worker" , which polls tasks from the default queue. If you want another worker listening to new_queue , clone the airflow-worker block and edit the command to "celery worker -q new_queue" .
